# Input next to button - Changing font size of button changes layout

Tags: css

I would like the input and the button to line up pixel perfectly. Why does changing the font size of a button element change the layout? I know this can fixed by changing the `vertical-align` style from baseline to something else, but I am not sure why I need to make this change? Is there another fix related to font sizing that would make these elements line up?

```css
input {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color:blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"><button>I</button>
```

Comment: Because text takes up space? Try `max-height`.

Comment: Try   display: flex in parent div of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Two inline-block elements with a specified height, but differ in font sizes, will not align as expected.

### Why?

Inline-block elements have a default `vertical-align` of `baseline`. This means when the font size is changed in either one of the inline-block elements, that element will keep its specified height, but shift to keep both elements text aligned.

[image: baseline causes mis-alignment]

### Correct Solution

Because `vertical-align:baseline` is causing the issue, setting this to either `bottom` or `top` is the proper fix. Both will have the same effect of lining up the elements by breaking up the bottom line of text.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! And it seems ```middle``` works too